# Standalone in-place precompilation using aspnet_compiler

Tags: asp.net

`aspnet_compiler` appears to have two modes:

1. **Target** - Entire site is copied to the target folder, `PrecompiledApp.config` is generated, generated assemblies go into target\bin, views are (optionally) replaced with placeholders
2. **In place** - Site is compiled in it's original location, no `PrecompiledApp.config` is generated, generated assemblies go into Temporary ASP.NET files, views are left as-is

Is it possible to trigger an in-place precompilation but have the generated assemblies + config also affect the original location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing this is not possible. Note that the two modes target very different scenarios:

1. **Target** mode is about creating bits that you can then deploy onto a server, such that it won't have to do as much compilation. Note that there are two sub-modes, depending on whether you make it updatable or not (-u switch).
2. **In place** mode is simply about warming up a site that is already deployed, such that the first request to it will be faster. Another way to look at it is that it's similar to manually requesting all the pages in your site to warm it up, except with a little less pain.

Note that if you do #1 in non-updatable mode, then even your .aspx (and related) files get modified to become stubs. So clearly, that could not happen in-place as that would end up deleting your original aspx files.

I'm not saying that it would be inconceivable to have some kind of hybrid mode that would do some of what Target mode does and keep it in the in-place bits. It's just not a scenario that the tool is targeting.

Comment: Deleting my aspx (cshtml in this case) files is acceptable, and is preferable to copying the entire web application (images included) to another place on the disk. Given that the web publishing process already copies all the files before packaging, the additional copy is causing build performance issues on larger sites. Anyways, thanks for the confirmation.

Comment: FYI, I can't award the bounty for another 22 hours.

Comment: If your goal is to precompile your Razor files, you might want to take a look at RazorGenerator (http://razorgenerator.codeplex.com/). Note that aspnet_compiler is sort of an aging tool, and I'm not sure I would recommend its use if there are alternatives.

Comment: I'm currently using `PrecompileBeforePublish` with the WPP, so aspnet_compiler came as part of that. Thanks for the heads up on razorgenerator, I'll check it out.